# Lower bound on growth function

Tags: computational-complexity, machine-learning

Prove that Sauer's lemma (theorem 3.17) is tight, i.e., for any set X of m > d elements, show that there exists a hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ of VC-dimension d such that $\Pi_\mathcal{H}(m) = \sum_{i=0}^d \binom{m}{i}$, where $\Pi_\mathcal{H}(m)$ is the growth function.

It is the exercise in the "Foundations of Machine Learning". I know that upper bounds : $\Pi_\mathcal{H}(m) \leq \sum_{i=0}^d \binom{m}{i}$ because it is shown in the chapter 3 of the textbook. Therefore, I have to prove the lower bound for some hypothesis set.
I assume that it is shown by decomposing $\sum_{i=0}^d \binom{m-1}{i}$ to $\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \binom{m-1}{i} + \sum_{i=0}^d \binom{m-1}{i}$. However I can't come up with other ideas to prove that.
Please tell me some idea.

Reference

Mohri, M., Rostamizadeh, A., and Talwalkar, A. (2018)  "Foundations of Machine Learning second edition" MIT Press.

Comment: Hint: Can you think of a combinatorial meaning for $\sum_{i = 0}^d \binom{m}{i}$? I.e., as a number of ways to select something from something? Does this suggest a $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: BTW, such classes are called 'maximum VC classes', and they have many nice properties. Googling the term should give you many non-trivial examples.